# jQuery: cannot add g-recaptcha div tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, recaptcha

I have this fragment of HTML:

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
<p class="gk-contact-fields">
  <input type="email" name="gk-contact-email" class="gk-required" placeholder="E-mail" value="">
  <input type="text" name="gk-contact-name" class="gk-required" placeholder="Name" value="">
</p>
```

I need to add a google recaptcha inside that section of the form, so I did:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.gk-contact-fields').append('<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LcjFgoUAAAAAG7kjR01GaS7-bS-ZOvZL2eMiGyC"></div>');
});
```

but nothing is showed. Or better, the div is created by it looks empty with nothing inside. Instead, if I add that tag as raw hmlt then it's showed and works.
What am I missing?

Comment: do not put in document ready

Comment: where instead??

Comment: just put  jQuery('.gk-contact-fields').append('<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LcjFgoUAAAAAG7kjR01GaS7-bS-ZOvZL2eMiGyC"></div>'); in <script> just below the google api script

Comment: or try an above aswell im not sure

Comment: fixed it!! thank you mate!! please explain me: why is ready function not good?

Comment: because the google script applies before document ready so when you append after document ready the script is not applied to that div